# Table header isn't shown in the table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager, jscrollpane

I want to make a score board. I am using table to show the data. The data will show, but the table header won't show. I have checked with other article and I have also put the `JScrollPane`.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Table {

    JFrame car;

    Table() {
        car = new JFrame();

        car.setTitle("Career");
        car.setSize(500, 500);
        car.setVisible(true);
        car.setLayout(null);

        String[] column = {"No.", "User Name", "Total Score"};
        String row[][] = {{"101", "Amit", "670000"},
        {"102", "Jai", "780000"},
        {"101", "Sachin", "700000"}};

        JTable jt = new JTable(row, column);
        jt.setBounds(20, 100, 225, 200);
        jt.setRowHeight(25);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jt);
        sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        car.add(sp);
        car.add(jt);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Table();
    }
}
```

From other website, I don't see any missing code here.
What is the problem?

Comment: 1) Remove this statement: `car.add(jt);`. The table is in the scroll pane, and the scroll pane has been added to the GUI 2) Also remove `car.setLayout(null);` &  `jt.setBounds(20,100,225,200);`. A `null` layout messes up many things, including how scroll panes work.

Comment: Thank you! The table is now showing. However the table has cover the whole Jframe. I want it to be at specific position and size.

Answer (score 3):

1. Remove this statement: `car.add(jt);`. The table is in the scroll pane, and the scroll pane has been added to the GUI
2. Also remove `car.setLayout(null);` & `jt.setBounds(20,100,225,200);`. A null layout messes up many things, including how scroll panes work.
3. Call `setVisible` after all components are added, and `pack()` is called.
4. Further changes needed, BNI.

### Result

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Table {

    JFrame car;

    Table() {
        car = new JFrame();

        car.setTitle("Career");
        // this is just a guess. Add components then pack()
        //car.setSize(500, 500);
        //car.setLayout(null);

        String[] column = {"No.", "User Name", "Total Score"};
        String row[][] = {{"101", "Amit", "670000"},
        {"102", "Jai", "780000"},
        {"101", "Sachin", "700000"}};

        JTable jt = new JTable(row, column);
        //jt.setBounds(20, 100, 225, 200);
        jt.setRowHeight(25);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jt);
        sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        car.add(sp);
        //car.add(jt);
        car.pack();
        // this statement should be last, immediately after pack()
        car.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Table();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I found our another way which I got what I want.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Table {

    JFrame car;

    Table() {
        car = new JFrame();
        car.setTitle("Career");
        car.setSize(500, 500);
        car.setVisible(true);
        car.setLayout(null);

        String[] column = {"No.", "User Name", "Total Score"};
        String row[][] = {{"101", "Amit", "670000"},
        {"102", "Jai", "780000"},
        {"101", "Sachin", "700000"}};

        JTable jt = new JTable(row, column);
        jt.setRowHeight(25);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jt);
        sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        sp.setBounds(20,100,225,200);
        car.add(sp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Table();
    }
}
```

Comment: (1-) Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.